# Kibana 3 Tables - How to do a left join

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Two Document Types are involved here:

```
[table1]
table1_id
column1
column2
column3

[table2]
table2_id
column4
column5
column6
table1_id
```

My goal is to create a table panel showing columns [column4, column5 and column6]. Coming from a relational standpoint, I will have to do:

```
table2 left join table1
```

How do i achieve this in Kibana? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new query "_type:table2", pinned it then, changed the table settings' Queries to "pinned".